# Succesfully return a connection instance MongoDb - Rust

Tags: mongodb, rust, rust-tokio

I'm learning rust, and I have been following the rust book. Usually, I try to implement something to strengthen my knowledge.

Recently I was looking into how to use the MongoDb create to create an instace and return the name of the database.

Here's a sample of what I have:

1. A folder containing a implementation to build a mongo connection string.
2. A .env file
3. A main function to get the info I need.

mongo_connection.rs

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ConnectionString {
    pub username: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub cluster: String,
}

impl ConnectionString {
    pub fn build_connection_string() -> String {
        return format!("mongodb+srv://{}:{}@a{}.k1jklnx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
        Self.username, Self.password, Self.cluster)
    }
}
```

main.rs

```rust
mod database;
use crate::database::mongo_connection;
use mongodb::{Client, options::ClientOptions};
use std::error::Error;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;
use tokio;

async fn create_database_connection() -> Client {
    dotenv().ok(); //Loading environment variables from .env file
    let connection_parameters = mongo_connection::ConnectionString{
        username: env::var("USERNAME").expect("No username found on .env"),
        password: env::var("PASSWORD").expect("No password found on .env"),
        cluster: env::var("CLUSTER").expect("No cluster found on .env")
    };
    let mut url: String = mongo_connection::ConnectionString::build_connection_string();
    println!("{}", url);
    let options = ClientOptions::parse(&url).await?;
    return Client::with_options(options).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let client = create_database_connection().await?;
    let db = client.database(&"runt");
    println!("{:?}", db.name());
    Ok(())
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I need to return a connection client. But I keep getting the Error:

```rust
let options = ClientOptions::parse(&url).await?;
    ^ cannot use the `?` operator in an async function that returns `Client`
```

If I change the result of the function to something like: `Result<Client, dyn Eq>`  then I get the error:

```rust
async fn create_database_connection() -> Result<Client, dyn Eq> {
`Eq` cannot be made into an object
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait cannot be made into an object because it uses `Self` as a type parameter
    |
```

Any advice on how to solve the error or any workaround is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the return type to either `Result<Client, mongodb::error::Error>` or `Result<Client, Box<dyn Error>>`. Either should work, but here's the code with the first version:

```
async fn create_database_connection() -> Result<Client, mongodb::error::Error> {
    dotenv().ok(); //Loading environment variables from .env file
    let connection_parameters = mongo_connection::ConnectionString{
        username: env::var("USERNAME").expect("No username found on .env"),
        password: env::var("PASSWORD").expect("No password found on .env"),
        cluster: env::var("CLUSTER").expect("No cluster found on .env")
    };
    let mut url: String = mongo_connection::ConnectionString::build_connection_string();
    println!("{}", url);
    let options = ClientOptions::parse(&url).await?;
    return Client::with_options(options).await;
}
```

In case you want to use the `Box<dyn Error>` version, the return value also needs a `.into()` to convert the `Result<Client, mongodb::error::Error>` of `Client::with_options()` into a `Result<Client, Box<dyn Error>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, when I implement the mongodb::error:Error, I get the following, it doesn't compile and I get the message:

error: the `Self` constructor can only be used with tuple or unit structs.

So, I guess I cannot access values in a struct using Self?

Comment: The solution for my latest problem was to have &self in the build_connection_string as a parameter, using that way to call the username, password and cluster attributes. Also, in the main.rs file, pass the struct to the function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice that but you were right to add a `&self` parameter. In main.rs it'd then be better to just call `connection_parameters.build_connection_string()`, that way Rust passes `&self` automatically.